# How to receive balance change notifications?

Tags: daemon, rpc, monero-wallet-rpc

Few days ago I asked on IRC how to receive notifications about incoming transactions and was pointed out that it's possible to do via freshly added 0MQ protocol.

Looking through the PR I didn't find much and as far and while documentation is being prepared I want to ask what is most effective strategy to receive change of balance notifications?

Answer (score 1):

With latest `monero-wallet-rpc` you can have an application run on each incoming tx to the wallet.

From the `--help`:

```
  --tx-notify arg         Run a program for each new incoming 
                          transaction, '%s' will be replaced by 
                          the transaction hash
```

Another simple solution is polling [incoming_transfers](https://ww.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#incoming_transfers).